# Absolute imports no longer work after upgrading to React Native 0.73

Tags: react-native

After upgrading from React native 0.72.5 to 0.73.0 my absolute imports no longer work. Until now, it has been working by just having a package.json file inside the folder `./App`, like this:

```
{ "name": "app" }
```

And then importing like this:

```
import asyncUpdater from 'app/utils/async-updater';
```

No extra Babel plugins or other custom configuration used.

Now, when I try to bundle, I get an error like this:

```
  1 | import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
  2 |
> 3 | import asyncUpdater from 'app/utils/async-updater';
    |                           ^
  4 | import cacheHashesUpdater from 'app/utils/cache-hashes-updater';
  5 |
  6 | import store from './store';.
Error: Unable to resolve module app/utils/async-updater from /Users/xxx/dev/0-mobile/App/index.ios.js: app/utils/async-updater could not be found within the project or in these directories:
```

I tried to upgrade by applying the changes shown in the
[React native upgrade helepr](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.72.5&to=0.73.0), expecting it to work like before.

Comment: Please share babel file? Ideally it should work. You might want to clear cache and start. Also remove metro's cache if any

Answer (score 0):

For me it is working again by including the package `yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver` and following changes to add the `module-resolver` plugin in `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  presets: [...],
  plugins: [
    ...
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        extensions: [
          '.ios.ts',
          '.ios.tsx',
          '.android.ts',
          '.android.tsx',
          '.ts',
          '.tsx',
          '.js',
          '.jsx',
          '.json',
        ],
        alias: {
          app: './app',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

This enables the alias for `app`. I had the same approach using a small `package.json` in the target folder, but yeah, this is my current fix.